# Android Loop Method Every X Seconds

Tags: android

I would like to call the same method, say every 5 seconds, I am trying to create some sort of database listener that will listen for database changes. The following code does not work, I am expecting the log to print "RUNNING" every 5 seconds for testing but this only gets called once when I call the method for the first time.

```
    private void DBListern() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //accessWebService();
        System.out.println("RUNNING");

        final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 

        DBListern(); 

       }

     }, 5000); 
}
```

Comment: why not add interfaces in places where you change database and realise them?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html) with its scheduleAtFixedRate you should be able to do exactly what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.
Example:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

private void DBListern(int delayInSeconds) {

    //accessWebService();
    System.out.println("RUNNING");

   exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DBListern();
            }
        }, delayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some reason the function cannot call itself so I created a different function called `loop()` which calls `DBListern` every 5 seconds:

```
private void DBListern() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   //accessWebService();
   System.out.println("RUNNING");

}


private void loop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 

            DBListern(); 
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }, 5000); 

}
```

So `loop()` is called first and then it calls `DBListern` every 5 seconds.

Comment: Your code can makes memory leaks.
You can use `Loader` to do this job, or event bus, or create some interfaces.